# Incompatibility in Python 3 functions (quote_from_bytes and unquote_to_bytes) results

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code:

```
src = b'\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf1\x23\x45\x67\x89\xab\xcd\xef\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a'
quoted = quote_from_bytes(src)
print(quoted)
unquoted = unquote_to_bytes(quoted)
print(unquoted)
```

I can't understand, why `print(unquoted)` returns
`b'\x124Vx\x9a\xbc\xde\xf1#Eg\x89\xab\xcd\xef\x124Vx\x9a'`

instead `b'\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a\xbc\xde\xf1\x23\x45\x67\x89\xab\xcd\xef\x12\x34\x56\x78\x9a'`

src is a sha1 hash.

I use Python 3.3 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does not use `\xab` escape codes for *printable* bytes. The `\x34` byte, for example, is shown as the printable `4` character instead:

```
>>> print(b'\x34')
b'4'
```

The same goes for every other byte in your value that can be displayed as a ASCII character instead; `\x56` is printed as `V`, `\x78` is shown as `x`, etc.

This is normal behaviour, the value is still the same:

```
>>> b'\x34' == b'4'
True
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is obvious. I need a recreation =)
I wonder why not conversely